# Why is take(1) used at the end of a retryWhen timer?

Tags: swift, timer, rx-swift, retry-logic

I'm looking reading from [RW book](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/rxswift).

```
.retryWhen { errors in
    return errors.enumerated().flatMap { (attempt, error) -> Observable<Int> in
        if attempt >= maxAttempts - 1 {
            return Observable.error(error)
        }
        return Observable<Int>.timer(Double(attempt + 1), scheduler:
            MainScheduler.instance).take(1)
    }
}
```

The timer isn’t taking a `period` Variable so it’s firing once and is not repeating. So why is it doing `take(1)`. I see that happening over a few times in the course of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `take(1)` is not necessary here. `take(1)` would have made sure that the timer doesn't repeat.

The `Observable.timer` is an operator that emits a value [periodically](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/70b8a33c5c3f4c3b15ebf10b638d2b15cfafb814/RxSwift/Observables/Timer.swift#L40). Unless the `period` parameter is still `nil`, in which case a `TimerOneOffSink` would be [created](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/70b8a33c5c3f4c3b15ebf10b638d2b15cfafb814/RxSwift/Observables/Timer.swift#L111). A `TimerOneOffSink` emits [one](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/70b8a33c5c3f4c3b15ebf10b638d2b15cfafb814/RxSwift/Observables/Timer.swift#L84) element and then completes and gets disposed of.

For example:

```
Observable<Int>
    .timer(3.0,
           scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .take(10)
    .subscribe(
        onNext:      { print($0) },
        onCompleted: { print("Completed") },
        onDisposed:  { print("Disposed") }
    )
```

would print:

```
0
Completed
Disposed
```

After consulting with **Marin Todorov**, one of the authors, he confirmed that it must be just an oversight.

The whole idea of the code snippet is to wait between retries using a timer with a duration increasing by 1 second: the result is an incremental back-off strategy with a maximum number of attempts.

Comment: If you don’t have the `period` then it’s non-repeating. Doesn’t that make it unnecessary?

Comment: @Honey yes it's not.

Comment: So the tutorial is confusing. Right?

Comment: @Honey yes. they have probably been using `interval` before some edit, it would have made sense with `take(1)`. Using `take(1)` with a timer that doesn't repeat is not wrong, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: You reached to him on Twitter? FWIW, the extra `take(1)` is on a few examples related to `retryWhen`. It’s not an a single that had that mistake

Comment: @Honey Yes. I did mention that. I have the first edition of that book

Comment: right. I was just asking because I wanted to know if he's responsive to tweets from people he doesn't know. I don't know if he knows you...